# Error in the symbol path when debug windows driver in Visual studio 2015 + WDK10

Tags: driver, windbg, wdk

I use host computer deploy and debug driver in target(win10 virtualbox, through serialport 1, baudrate:115200), I can load driver into target and check with command "!lmi filedisk", It was loaded. But It did not hit any break points.
I checked ".reload -f" and it showed up:

```
    kd> .sympath
Symbol search path is: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols;https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols;https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
Deferred                                       https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Deferred                                       srv*
kd> .reload -f
Connected to Windows 10 14393 x64 target at (Fri Apr 28 23:01:42.142 2017 (UTC + 7:00)), ptr64 TRUE
Loading Kernel Symbols
..

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..........*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for clipsp.sys - 
................................*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for VBoxGuest.sys - 
...................
................*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for VBoxSF.sys - 
.......*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for FileDisk.SYS
...*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for windrvr1230.sys
.......*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for VBoxMouse.sys - 
..*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for VBoxVideoW8.sys - 
....*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for drmk.sys - 
.........*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MadBus.sys
................
..........................*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for peauth.sys
.......
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
.......Unable to enumerate user-mode unloaded modules, Win32 error 0n30

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
clipsp                 The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       Signature does not match : C:\Users\3aoThinh95\AppData\Local\DBG\sym\clipsp.pdb\82BF23951435468AA821A930107751181\clipsp.pdb
                       Signature does not match : C:\Users\3aoThinh95\AppData\Local\DBG\sym\clipsp.pdb\2B15CA722B65427FAB9EF42232CFD9BD1\clipsp.pdb
                       Signature does not match : C:\Users\3aoThinh95\AppData\Local\DBG\sym\clipsp.pdb\82BF23951435468AA821A930107751181\clipsp.pdb
VBoxGuest              The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
VBoxSF                 The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
FileDisk               The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
windrvr1230            The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
VBoxMouse              The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
VBoxVideoW8            The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
drmk                   The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
MadBus                 The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
peauth                 The system cannot find the file specified : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
                       The system cannot find the file specified : https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
                       PDB not found : cache*
                       The system cannot find the file specified : SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That are 3rd party drivers/DLL (some from Oracle VirtualBox and other 3rd party DLLs), which are not available on Microsoft Symbol Server.

The `drmk.sys` is Microsoft Trusted Audio Drivers and for some audio/DRM related files, Microsoft is also not offering PDBs to prevent reverse engineering.

For your own drivers, you have to add your own PDBs to the symbol search path.

Comment: actually, this project is belong to https://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/ . windows driver examples. then, how can I find information about this PDBs file?

Comment: when you compile the driver,the linker generated the sys + PDB in Checked/Release folder (depending on what you compile). Add this output folder to Windbg symbol paths

Answer (score 0):

It appears that none of the directories in your symbol path contains the symbol file for this driver. That's why breakpoints cannot be set.

Make sure you have this driver symbol in a directory and then add this directory as part of the symbol path by executing command .sympath+ [full path to your symbol directory]